# Was the latex font changed?

Tags: support, mathjax, font

Since today the latex font on my tablet looks different than yesterday. Was it changed?

What can I do to get yesterday 's font back?

I will post a screen shot when I figured out how to...

Comment: I don't notice any difference. There are [a lot of posts on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Btex%5D+font) where people report a font change in MathJax, they all seem to have different causes. Have you looked through them to see if any of them solve your problem?

Comment: To admit no. Searching on my tablet is a pain...] thanks for the link.

Comment: Did you update your OS recently?  Such an update could have installed the STIX fonts for you, and in that case, MathJax will select the local STIX fonts in favor of the web-based MathJax fonts (they will work faster).  But they do look different, and some people prefer the MathJax fonts.  If you like the MathJax fonts better, you could install them from [the GitHub repository](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/tree/master/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/otf).

Comment: @DavideCervone not that I recognized, but maybe an automatic process. I'll have to check. Thanks for the hint...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For sake of providing an answer and not leaving this question dangling, I just experienced a font change as well. There is 100% correlation between this change and my recent install of STIX fonts.

If you find STIX fonts in your OS's fonts folder, then it appears they will be preferentially used.